# Django/Pinax UTF8 encoding

Tags: python, mysql, django, utf-8, pinax

I have scrumdo http://scrumdo.org installed on a CentOS server which I'm trying to move to a slackware server. On CentOS I installed LAMP and I believe pinax with yum, and on slackware I used downloaded tars for the most part.

Scrumdo runs fine on CentOS but on Slackware it throws this error when trying to create a project from the database:

```
DjangoUnicodeDecodeError at /projects/create/
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 0: invalid continuation byte. You passed in '\xf19pt5xb' (<type 'str'>)
```

I noticed my CentOS db is latin1_ci and my slackware database is utf8. I tried specifying utf8 in /etc/my.cnf for the server and client and restarting mysql but it still produced the error. I then tried truncating the slackware database and importing the CentOS tables, but still the same error.

In a long shot I tried just copying the entire CentOs scrum directory, but I received an error about timesince model not being installed, and python manage.py syncdb could not detect it was in a pinax environment despite it being activated. Right now I'm running a file comparison on the two directories to see if there is a character encoding setting in python, django, or pinax I can change.

Comment: `I tried specifying utf8 in /etc/my.cnf for the server and client and restarting mysql but it still produced the error.` - where/how did you specify this?

Comment: in /etc/my.cnf I put under [client] `default-character-set = utf8` and under [mysqld] `collation_server = utf8_general_ci` `init_connect='set collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci;'`